# How to rename database and files with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm building a patch-application that modifies an existing MS SQL database. There are multiple steps the user goes through during the patch, but no changes are made till the end.

The program uses Entity Framework in order to read and write data to the database, and i'm collecting all changes within a single transaction so that i can rollback any time.

However, now i need to be able to rename the database on the SQL Server (and it's files)... Is this achievable with Entity Framework, to be contained within the same transaction as the other operations? If yes, how? And will the connection be broken once the database is renamed?

Comment: dbup: https://dbup.github.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF is not able to do that. Use SMO, it has [Database.Rename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.rename.aspx) method and it is much more appropriate tool to work with db schema:

```
Server srv = new Server(conn);
Database database = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks"];
database.Rename("newName");
```

Comment: Would such action kill the connection of the EF-transaction?

Comment: Generally you will not be able to perform renaming until any active connections exist. Even you execute `ALTER DATABASE` statement you will receive 'The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation' error if database is in use. So just commit the transaction before renaming and make sure the EF connection has been closed.